# MVC 5 javascript not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Any javascript I embed in a view is not firing. A dummy sample code

```
<a href="javascript:getView();" name="something" id="something">click me </a>

<div id="AddAY"></div>


<script type="text\javascript">
    function getView()
    {
                $('#AddAY').load('/schools/details/2');
     };


</script>
```

When the page is rendered the result is :

```
<a href="javascript:getView();" name="something" id="something">click me</a>

<div id="AddAY"></div>


<script type="text\javascript">
    function getView()
    {
                $('#AddAY').load('/schools/details/2');
     };


</script>


    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.11.1.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
```

when you click on the link, it does nothing.

Comment: should the jquery source code be declared before the function? This: $('#AddAY').load('/schools/details/2');  has not meaning until this <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script> (and the other files) are rendered.

Comment: @ADASein No. `getView` is only called when link is clicked.

Comment: This is basic web programming: move the jquery libraries to the top so the browser can parsing the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All thanks for the helpfull tips. I'll take them into mind to write better code. But after two days of struggling it turned out to be a stupid TYPO.

The way I did found it might be helpfull to others.

I put the code in another project where javascript does get fired. Just to rule out that (although I had no clue which) it was not some kind of configuration issue in my project.

In the other project it did fire, which let me believe it actually was a configuration issue. :-( And sending me of on the wrong track.

I ended up comparing my code on two screens side by side, line by line. Comparing the output (source of html page) line by line. but did not found any difference, until at a given moment I noticed that the in one project was more colorfull than in the other. This was a crucial hint. It may me think "why is intellisense not picking up ?" and than I came to the conclusion "because intellisense does not know it is javascript". Then I noticed the stupid TYPO. A \ where it should have been /

```
<script type="text\javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: You can remove `type` altogether and will still work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting anchor tag href the value of your function (javascript:getView();) replace your code with this one:

```js
<a href="#" name="something" id="myFunction">click me </a>

<div id="AddAY"></div>


<script type="text\javascript">
  
    $('#myFunction').click(function(){

         $('#AddAY').load('/schools/details/2');
  
    });
  


</script>
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/0tvnot76/)